# is possible rating star from json value?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

i wondering it is possible to get a populate the glyphicon-star from the json value in ajax? i have a json file like this:

```
[
  {
    "star": 4
  },{
    "star": 3
  },{
   "star": 5
  }
]
```

and in my ajax:

```
$(function($){
  $.ajax({
    url: './dataModel/star.json',
    method: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      for(var i = 0; i < data; i++){
        output = '';

        // if i do like this then will not populate the glyphicon-star -
        // from the value of star in json.
        output += '<p class="glyphicon glyphicon-star">' + data[i].star + '</p>';
        $('.star').html(output);
      }
    }
  })
})
```

i wondering if someone can teach me how to populate that.
any suggestion and idea i thank you so much.
kind of regard, 
ape

Comment: Please include the desired html that you're trying to populate in the `for` loop

Comment: @AlonEitan thank you for your feedback. the html file is only a div. like: <div class="star"></div>

Comment: Your main issue is that you're overriding the content of every `.star` inside your loop at `$('.star').html(output);`. At the end you'll have only visible the last iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build your HTML (inside the `for` or `forEach`) using String concatenation.
Than append the finished product only once. After the loop.

(I used [**FontAwesome**](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) for demo, you replace the `fa fa-star` with `glyphicon glyphicon-star`)

```js
var data = [
  {
    "name" : "Piggy the Cat",
    "star": 4
  },{
    "name" : "Alice in Foobar",
    "star": 3
  },{
    "name" : "Lorem the Ipsum",
    "star": 5
  }
];


// success: function(data) {
var HTML = ""; // Start the HTML string for concatenation
data.forEach(function( ob ) {
  for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {  // We need 5 stars
    var icoClass = i<ob.star ? "fa fa-star" : "fa fa-star-o"; // full or empty star?
    HTML += "<i class='"+ icoClass +"'></i>"; // concatenate stars
  }
  HTML += " "+ ob.name +"<br>"; // and concatenate the cool movie name
});
document.getElementById("movies").innerHTML = HTML; // Finally insert
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="movies"></div>
```

---

#### There's another *JS-simpler* way, but involves a bit of CSS.

This time the JS speaks by it-self:

```js
var data = [
  {
    "name" : "Piggy the Cat",
    "star": 4
  },{
    "name" : "Alice in Foobar",
    "star": 3
  },{
    "name" : "Lorem the Ipsum",
    "star": 5
  }
];

// success: function(data) {
var HTML = "";
data.forEach(function( ob ) {
  HTML += "<i class='star-"+ ob.star +"'></i> "+ ob.name +"<br>";
});
document.getElementById("movies").innerHTML = HTML;
```

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css");
i[class^=star-]:after{font: normal normal 16px/1 FontAwesome;}
.star-1:after{content:"\f005\f006\f006\f006\f006";}
.star-2:after{content:"\f005\f005\f006\f006\f006";}
.star-3:after{content:"\f005\f005\f005\f006\f006";}
.star-4:after{content:"\f005\f005\f005\f005\f006";}
.star-5:after{content:"\f005\f005\f005\f005\f005";}
```

```html
<div id="movies"></div>
```

https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

---

#### Good "news"?

You don't need any special font to get Unicode Character Stars:

> ★    &#9733;    \2605
>   ☆    &#9734;    \2606

```css
.star-3:before{content:"\2605\2605\2605\2606\2606";}
```

```html
<span class="star-3"> Good News!</span>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your solution. is working! thanks alot. :)